# C# Open Instance Delegate covariance and abstract data

Tags: c#, delegates, covariance

stackoverflow. I'm new to C#, but have experience in C++ and I got stuck with one idea realization:

I want to make an object with abstract properties(not C# properties, but variables) as a base class and N derived classes with such inheritance:

```
ObjWithProps <-- A <-- B <-- N other classes derived one from another
```

Properties list is static, so it will be initialized once per type, not per object. Each of A and B can add own abstract properties with unique string-represented names. First of all I was thinking of making it with **OpenInstanceDelegates**, but it turns out, that delegates *can't be covariant*, am I right ?

```
public delegate T OpenGetterDlg<T>(ObjWithProps instance);
```

I can't simply bind function `A.GetSomething()` to `OpenGetterDlg` because of different `this` parameter and covariance doesn't works here.

I could do that instead:

```
public delegate TPropType OpenGetterDlg<TPropType, TThisType>(TThisTypeinstance);
```

but it becomes real pain in the ass when dealing with a list of

```
class CPropWrapper<TPropType, TInstType> where TInstType : ObjWithProps
{
  // Property ID here
  // Setter Delegate object here
  // Getter Delegate object here
}
```

Too many casts, too many type params, too many templates ... Maybe someone knows how do that task in C# ? The key ideas: static prop list, any derived classes (A, B, C, D) can add their own props to list, encapsulated and minimal type specification.

**Thanks in advance!**

**UPD1:**
Pseudocode

```
class ObjWithProps
{
  class CPropertyWrapper
  {
     public string Name;
     public OpenGetterDelegate Getter;
     public OpenSetterDelegate Setter;
  }

  static List<CpropertyWrapper> AbstractProps;

  public CProperty GetPropertyByName(string name)
  {
     // Find property by name and
     return PropertyFromType(Getter());
  }
}
```

CProperty is a base wrapper class for types like int, float, myType1, myType2.

```
class A: ObjWithProps
{
  int IQValue;

  public int getIQ() { return IQValue; }
  public void setIQ(int iq) { IQValue = iq; }

  protected override registerProps()
  {
    // this one should be called only once
    registerProperty<int>("IQ", "getIQ", "setIQ");
  }
}

class B: A
{
  myType1 X;

  public myType1 getX() { return X; }
  public void setX(myType1 x) { X= x; }

  protected override registerProps()
  {
    base.registerProps();
    registerProperty<myType1>("X", "getX", "setX");
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show pseudo-code, which describes what you want? What is a "property"? Is it just a name, or a name with value? If so, how do you want to access that value?

Comment: If I haven't misunderstood your question, can't you use a simple Dictionary<string, object>?

Comment: @Mones, and what class will be stored as object ?

Comment: @JacksonRR in your example you aren't doing any kind of special elaborations.. just value storing. If you don't have to perform any elaborations on the data you can simple store them in a Dictionary, defining keys as constants.

Answer (score 1):

At first look, you want to re-invent [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) from WPF. At least, I can't see any conceptual differences.

Comment: Dennis, thanks a lot. Didn't know that this system already exist. However, I need to use it on different platforms, so System.Windows doesn't sounds really good. So ... is there any chance to copy WPF PropertySystem with smart delegates implementation or it is hopeless ?

Comment: At my system the stuck point is -- a connection of actual getters/setters with PropertyWrapper via delegates. Maybe you could give a tip on that ?

Comment: @JacksonRR: I'm not a Mono developer, but in your case I would look at Mono (and even abandoned Moonlight) - may be they have implemented DP mechanism. It isn't a WPF specific indeed.